# Gradle dependencies on source set of different projects

Tags: java, gradle, build

I'm working in a multiproject system (with 40+ subprojects). Each subproject has its own layout (most follows a common layout, but some differ).
Among the subprojects I have these two:

```
- testjunit
    - sourceSets
        - lptfExperimental
        - other source sets

- basicservices
    - sourceSets
        - testacceptance
        - other source sets
```

I need to make the source set `basicservices-testacceptance` depend on the output of source set `testjunit-lptfExperimental`.

I tried to do:

```
dependencies{
    testacceptanceCompile project(':testjunit').sourceSets.lptfExperimental.output
}
```

And

```
dependencies{
    project.parent.subprojects.each{prj ->
    if(prj.name == "testjunit")
        testacceptanceCompile prj.sourceSets.findByName('lptfExperimental').output
}
```

But in both cases I receive the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>   Script 'C:\Development\defaults.gradle' line: 144
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   Could not find property 'lptfExperimental' on SourceSet container.

Just an extra info: this dependency is declared in a file named `defaults.gradle` that is applied in `build.gradle` of project `basicservices`.

## /defaults.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
...
sourceSets {
    ...
    // test acceptance
    testacceptance{

        java{
            srcDir 'test/acceptance/src/java'
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'test/acceptance/src/java'
        }
    }
    ...
}

// default dependencies
dependencies{
    testacceptanceCompile project(':testjunit')
    testacceptanceCompile project(':testjunit').sourceSets.lptfExperimental.output
}
...
```

## /testjunit/build.gradle:

```
...
sourceSets{
    ...
    lptfExperimental{

    java {
        srcDir 'lptf-experimental/src/java'
    }

    resources {
        srcDir 'lptf-experimental/src/java'
    }
}
...
```

## /basicservices/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply from: '../defaults.gradle'

dependencies{
    ...
    compile project(':testjunit')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem with the solution mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347364/gradle-multiproject-gives-could-not-find-property-sourcesets-on-project-erro).
Basically, I added a directive `evaluationDependsOn(':testjunit')` in `defaults.gradle`. It solved the problem. The reference for this directive is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).