# Clover code coverage behavior differs between Maven and Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, code-coverage, clover

I am migrating a Maven Project to Gradle and I have an issue with my code coverage plugin : Clover. I have an unexplained behavior about coverage computation. Let's take a simple example :

```
// ProjectA

class A
{
    void method1()
    {
        // Some stuff
        // This method is covered by a unit test in ProjectA
    }

    void method2()
    {
        // Some stuff
        // This method is not covered by any unit test in ProjectA
    }
}

// ProjectB

class B
{
    void method3()
    {
        new A().method2();
        // Some stuff
        // This method is covered by a unit test in ProjectB
    }
}
```

I have 2 different project : `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. `ProjectB` depends on `ProjectA`.

`ProjectA` contains a class named `A`. `method1` from `A` is covered by a unit test contained in `ProjectA`. `method2` is not covered by any test contained in `ProjectA`.

`ProjectB` contains a class named `B`. `method3` from `B` is covered by a unit test contained in `ProjectB`. `method3` calls `method2` from class `A` in `ProjectA`.

The fact :

With Maven and Clover (official plugin), `method2` is considered covered as it's call from a method (`method3`) covered by a unit test, even if the test is in a different project.
With Gradle and Clover ([unofficial plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin)), `method2` is considered uncovered as there is no dedicated test in `ProjectA`.

The configuration is kind of basic, no major difference between Maven and Gradle Clover plugin.

My questions :

What is the normal / default behavior of Clover ?
Can this behavior be set through configuration ?
Or is this some kind of bug in the Gradle Clover plugin ?

Comment: Are you tied to clover? In my opinion [JaCoCo](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) is superior to clover since it instruments on-the-fly (using a java agent) without manipulating class files. It's the de-facto standard for gradle builds

Comment: But on-the-fly instrumentation does not work with Powermock https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo

Comment: Hehe... so switch to [mockito](http://site.mockito.org) too then... (half kidding, half not!)

Comment: Also using Mockito but PowerMockito too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we've got the fun out of the way and ruled out JaCoCo, I think you'll need to provide clover with [additional source dirs](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/clover/CloverPluginConvention.groovy#L34)

Eg:

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.clover'

evaluationDependsOn ':someOtherProject'    
clover {
    additionalSourceDirs = project(':someOtherProject').sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I will test it and get back to you.

Comment: I had an issue with your answer, a `Could not find property 'sourceSets'` issue, related to this question i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347364/gradle-multiproject-gives-could-not-find-property-sourcesets-on-project-erro Anyway, I hardcoded the path of `ProjectA` (for the sake of the test, temporarily) and it worked ! My clover.xml file at the root of the project was filled with the proper coverage. I have to figure out this sourceSets issue but my initial issue is fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer to include `evaluationDependsOn ':someOtherProject'`

Comment: Actually I did not use `evaluationDependsOn`, my project architecture was a little too complex for that but moving the instruction to a better place did the job. Anyway, it does not change the fact that the initial answer was perfectly accurate.